# NetworkX errors while adding nodes: "unhashable type: 'dict'" and "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Tags: python-3.5, networkx, dictionary-comprehension

While running the below NetworkX python 3.5 code (within Jupyter) I get an error that I don't really understand. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os, warnings     
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'


## NODES

a = [ (  'a_%d' % i, {'a' : i}) for i in range(0,5) ]
b = [ (  'b_%d' % i, {'b' : i}) for i in range(0,5) ]
c = [ (  'c_%d' % i, {'c' : i}) for i in range(0,5) ]
d = [ (  'd_%d' % i, {'d' : i}) for i in range(0,5) ]

E = [ (  'E_%d' % h, {'a': i}, {'b': j}, {'c': k}, {'d': l} )
        for h in range(1,626) for i in range(0,5) 
        for j in range(0,5) for k in range(0,5) 
        for l in range(0,5) ]

## GRAPH initialization

testgraph = nx.Graph()
list_of_nodegroups = [a, b, c , d, E]
```

And this is where it fails:

```
## GRAPH construction - adding nodes

for ng1 in list_of_nodegroups1:
    testgraph.add_nodes_from(ng1)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py in add_nodes_from(self, nodes_for_adding, **attr)
    535             try:
--> 536                 if n not in self._node:
    537                     self._adj[n] = self.adjlist_inner_dict_factory()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-718f064c86a3> in <module>()
      1 for ng1 in list_of_nodegroups:
----> 2     testgraph.add_nodes_from(ng1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py in add_nodes_from(self, nodes_for_adding, **attr)
    540                     self._node[n].update(attr)
    541             except TypeError:
--> 542                 nn, ndict = n
    543                 if nn not in self._node:
    544                     self._adj[nn] = self.adjlist_inner_dict_factory()

    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Referring to (as I understand it) 2 things:

- "unhashable type: 'dict'"
- "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

I am trying to figure out how exactly this could be solved, whether within this code or elsewhere, and any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:

My objective is to have a graph consisting of 4 types of 'children-nodes' being a,b,c,d and 1 type of 'mother-nodes' being E, like this:

```
[ ('E1', {'a0': 0, 'b0': 0, 'c0': 0, 'd0': 0} ),
  ('E2', {'a1': 1, 'b0': 0, 'c0': 0, 'd0': 0} ),
  ('E3', {'a1': 1, 'b1': 1, 'c0': 0, 'd0': 0} ),
   ...
  ('E625', {'a5': 5, 'b5': 5, 'c5': 5, 'd5': 5} ),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation for `Graph.add_nodes_from(nodes_for_adding, **attr)`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from.html): `nodes_for_adding` (iterable container) – A container of nodes (list, dict, set, etc.). OR A container of (node, attribute dict) tuples. Node attributes are updated using the attribute dict.

Each element in your list `E` is a tuple containing one node and 4 dicts, while `add_nodes_from` only accepts a single dict. Those 4 dicts should be merged into a single dict: `{'a': i, 'b': j, 'c': k, 'd': l}`.

Also, the list `E` has 625 × 5⁴ = 390625 elements. Is this your intention, or you are trying to enumerate the node? If you want to enumerate, it does not work as you expected. Instead, use

```
from itertools import product

E = [('E_%d' % h, {'a': i, 'b': j, 'c': k, 'd': l})
     for h, (i, j, k, l) in enumerate(product(range(5), repeat=4), start=1)]
```

Comment: Thanks @ducminh You're right about the dicts having to be one (not 4 separate, I overlooked that. My only goal is to have 4 sub-types of nodes, each with n variation (5 in this example). And a 5th 'mother'-type that stores all possible combinations between them: 5^4 625. But I 
might have noted that down incorrectly.

Comment: If you are using `for h in ... for i in ...` that way, it will produce a list of 390625 elements, but only 625 nodes will be added. For example, there will be two tuples `('E1', {...})` and `('E1', {...})`, and the first node produced by the first tuple will be overwritten by the second tuple. You can try with smaller values to see the effect.